# Decrease firestore reads

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I using firebase in my android app. All data is stored in firestore documents. It will have various car companies' names on the home page, if user clicks on a company then model names will be displayed and finally information about that car. The app is in development still it is having around 250 document reads a day. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Is it a good idea to have companies' and their model names in realtime database and info about that particular car in firestore document? for ex. (please ignore the syntax) `db.collections("Ferrari").document("458").getResults()`

will this kind of query count as 1 document read? And can I reduce documents read this by this way?

Answer (score 0):

**For Document**

> Charges for reads have some nuances that you should keep in mind. The
> following sections explain these nuances in detail.

**Listening to query results**

> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get
> realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
> also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
> because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
> deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

**Managing large result sets**

> Cloud Firestore has several features to help you manage queries that
> return a large number of results:
>
> Cursors, which allow you to resume a long-running query. Page tokens,
> which help you paginate the query results. Limits, which specify how
> many results to retrieve. Offsets, which allow you to skip a fixed
> number of documents.
>
> There are no additional costs for using cursors, page tokens, and
> limits. In fact, these features can help you save money by reading
> only the documents that you actually need.
>
> However, when you send a query that includes an offset, you are
> charged a read for each skipped document. For example, if your query
> uses an offset of 10, and the query returns 1 document, you are
> charged for 11 reads. Because of this additional cost, you should use
> cursors instead of offsets whenever possible.

**Queries other than document reads**

> For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of
> collection IDs, you are billed for one document read. If fetching the
> complete set of results requires more than one request (for example,
> if you are using pagination), you are billed once per request.

**If we come to your question.**

This example shows how to get the content of a **single** document using get ()

```
db.collections("Ferrari").document("458").get() // One Document One Read :)
```

**Note** : There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.